# how to skip the dynamic arguments when it is empty in payloadFactory wso2 esb as XML

Tags: wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB, and we are using payloadFactory mediator to transform the message. we have entered into scenario where we need to ignore the payload arguments when it is empty or null. can any one help us achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using filter mediator wherein you check the arguments in xpath, if arguments exist then you can call payload mediator with all the arguments, else you can call another payload which doesn't contain those arguments.
However according to me the best practice would be to use an xslt mediator where you put all your logic in the xslt, this would make your sequence small in length and more readable.